# How can I use an Excel cell, or range, as parameter(s) for an Azure SQL Database query (in Excel) and append that query to my Excel cell, or range

Tags: sql, excel, azure-sql-database

I want to be able to paste some value in an Excel cell or range of cells, then hit refresh (to run a query) and then pull in details from an Azure SQL Database to append onto those numbers.

```
HAVING f.AssetNumber in ('9091300368')
```

I want to pass the Excel parameters in the HAVING f.AssetNumber in ('Excel parameter(s)')

This is the desired result. A2 is the parameter and the rest is queried data
[image: Screenshot of Desired Result]

Comment: You've mentioned "**A2**" is the parameter, but the screenshot doesn't show the column/row names.

Comment: You could use Power Query to get your desired result

Comment: @Gangula, you're right. A2 would be the cell under AssetNumber. How would I use Power Query for this?

Comment: Hope this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/63d15491-21d7-4ad6-bd2a-cdf5b4c03697/ms-query-pass-user-entered-parameter-from-excel-to-access-query?forum=exceldev) might help